# failure to update the update statement in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have got this statement

```
     mysql_query("
 UPDATE topic
 SET tag_h1='$tag_h1', tag_h2='$tag_h2',tag_metadata='$tag_metadata',content='$content',title='$title', friendly_url='$friendlyUrl'
 WHERE topic_id=$topic_id
 ") or die(mysql_error());
```

it works with small text in English. But large amount of text in hebrew (above 400 characters) results in an exception.. It is conventional for php code not to display any error in chrome, firefox, and any other browser.. so I cant tell you, what the particular mistake is..

But i tested the thing..and the statement works and doesnt work depending on how much text you provide it and in what language?!?

the "content" field is the culprit and it is set as a "text" datatype..

How do I show errors?:

> ```
>   display_errors
> ```
>
> Default Value: On
>    Development Value: On
>     Production Value: Off
>
> error_reporting
>    Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
>    Development
>   Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
>     Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
>
> Do i unmark all the above?

Comment: I am wondering whay this user is not banned yet.

Comment: lol.. Shrapnel..if only php was showing its errors like asp.net did..i wouldnt even visit this site

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel he would probably just reappear under a different name. Unfortunately.

Comment: very true..Anony..But to make you a favor..that will be one of the last questions that I will ask..cause after i finish my site..this site..i am going to shift to asp.net mvc and leave that noob php for the noob php programmers

Comment: ... until you realize that *escaping strings* is also necessary in any other language, at which point you will again show up here and cry why your asp.niet programs don't work either...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse At least it will take off his ability to leave abusing and ignorant comments.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the same character set throughout the entire script/database pipeline? If there's a charset change anywhere throughout, you'll end up with a garbage query and syntax errors.

As for not displaying errors, you can change that quite simply with `display_errors` and `error_reporting` .ini settings in PHP. The `or die(...)`. If nothing else, PHP should be logging errors in a file somewhere anyways.

Without knowing what the error (if any) is, this question can't be answered in any reasonable form beyond vague advice like this. Have you tried outputting the generated query string and executing it yourself in the mysql monitor?

Comment: do I need to restart xamp after making the changes?!?

Comment: in the .ini file, yes. any changes there require a restart.

Comment: but the localhost works.. i can operate my website..i have all my tables set as ..All my tables are: utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: That means very little. two different servers, two different environments. Have you checked every single setting on both machines? I doubt it...

Comment: would using this: mysql_set_charset  before my update command help?

Comment: Most likely you just need to **escape your strings**.

Answer (score 1):

Using `text` as the field type in MySQL allows up to 65536 characters, so that shouldn't be causing any issues with 400 character long values.

However, one thing that can cause a big issue - especially if you are using Hebrew characters, is the character set. Since you are using English, and Hebrew, it's worth trying `UTF-8` as the character set. Your MySQL table should be changed to this character set, and also the content field.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your character set encodings are specified correctly. Consider using the newer `mysqli` interface, prepared statements and **escape your strings properly**.

Right now, the code fragment you shared, is a classic **sql injection vulnerability**.

And **Seriously**. I know that you do not care about security. But you should care about *bugs*. And security issues usually indicate a severe kind of bugs. String escaping *can* be exploited, but only because it is a bug in the first place to not escape the strings properly. It will fail also without malicious intend. It will not delete your database or anything then, but just lose some random records. **Even if you don't care about security, losing random records due to bad characters should still concern you**!